# Tesseract says it isn't installed

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

so I'm trying to make a project that takes words from a picture and types them, but I can't for the life of me get tesseract to work. Here's my code (don't worry about the commented out stuff)

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time
import os
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
import pyautogui 
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(2)
#words = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
#for i in words:
    #keyboard.press(i)
    #keyboard.release(i)
    #time.sleep(0.01)

#Takes a screenshot. You can pass a four-integer tuple of the left, top, width, and height of the region.
image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,400, 800, 100)) 
#Saves to disk
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) 
cv2.imwrite("image1.png", image) 
#Define path to tessaract.exe
path_to_tesseract = 'D:\Tesseract\tesseract.exe'

#Define path to image
path_to_image = 'Screenshot 2023-10-30 181253.png'

#Point tessaract_cmd to tessaract.exe
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'D:\Tesseract\tesseract.exe'

#Open image with PIL
img = Image.open('Screenshot 2023-10-30 181253.png')

#Extract text from image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```